# function to verify all cells in active row

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a function which is triggered `onEdit` to enter an ID in new table entries:

```
function IdGenerator(e) {
  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  

  // Get the active row             
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();

  // Get the next ID value (Auto-increment this cell with =MAX(Sheet1!A:A)+1)
  var id = sheet.getRange("'Config and Data'!B2").getValue();

  // Check if ID column is empty
  if (sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue() == "") {
    // Set new ID value
    sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(id);                        
  }
}
```

Currently this script only checks if the cell in ID column is empty. I need to modify so that:

*If all cells in the active row are empty then do **NOT** write the ID, else **DO** write the ID.*

Comment: But the `onEdit` is triggered from that particular row, isn't? Most likely it will contain a value and thus an `ID` needs to be created.

Comment: You are right of course, the problem is that the onEdit is also triggered by a deletion in any of the cells (also when deleting an empty cell), causing IDs to be generated also for empty lines.. I'm looking for a kind of 'if COUNTA(row,row)=0 then exit'..